# Como agregar un contador incremental en una consulta join

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

tengo el siguiente problema y ojalá me puedan ayudar.

Tengo una consulta grande que simplificaré para explicar donde tengo el problema. Tengo 2 tablas que necesito cruzar para obtener un dato de la segunda, cuando ejecuto la primera consulta me sale ordenado los datos tal como fueron ingresados y que representa un reporte, cuando hago un join o leftjoin para agregar el dato que necesito de la segunda tabla se me desordena todas las filas en que venía la primera tabla, probé cambiando el join por left join pero sucede lo mismo.

No hay caso que se pueda ordenar igual que viene la primera tabla (la cual no tiene ningún order by, ni tampoco ninguna columna que sirva para ordenar). Lo que se me ocurrió fue poner un row_number() en la primera tabla, cosa que al hacer el cruce tenga este valor que mantiene el orden y luego en el cruce poner el order by basada en esta columna nueva que indica la posición en que quiero que aparezcan las filas. Pero cuando pongo el row_number, por ejemplo:

row_number() OVER () me va repitiendo el contador y no queda como un incremental, la otra opción es poner dentro del OVER un order by, pero volvemos al problema inicial, no sé por qué sucede esto. Pondré un ejemplo para que se entienda, en este caso la columna llamada "orden" es la que se agrega al poner el row_number().

TABLA PRINCIPAL CON EL ROW_NUMBER()

| Nombre1 | Nombre2 | Target_id | etapa | orden |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Juan | Pérez | 10000 | 0 | 1 |
| Juan | Pérez | 10000 | 1 | 1 |
| Juan | González | 60000 | 0 | 2 |
| Juan | González | 50000 | 0 | 2 |
| Juan | González | 80000 | 0 | 2 |
| Juan | González | 70000 | 0 | 2 |

Este vendría siendo el resultado de la primera tabla y está ordenada tal como quiero, si intento agregar el row_number para usarlo con el cruce con la segunda tabla, me sale exactamente como se ve en la columna **orden**, en vez de generar 1,2,3,4,5,6... y luego poder hacer el order by, me sale como agrupado 1,1,2,2,2,2,2 etc...

¿Alguien sabe por qué esto? O hay otra manera de hacer esta consulta. Ya que solo necesito un contador que agregue la posición de cada fila de la primera tabla, para cuando luego haga el cruce poder ordenar basado en esta fila.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

En SQL, los conjuntos de datos, incluyendo las tablas, no tienen ningún orden por defecto.

El hecho de que el motor te devuelva las filas *en el orden en que fueron ingresadas* es una mera casualidad y es algo que no necesariamente se va a cumplir todas las veces, sobre todo si la tabla sufre actualizaciones, borrados e inserciones. Va a haber un punto en que esa *fantasía* va a romperse (quizás ya lo ha hecho y no te has dado cuenta).

En SQL se dice que el orden es *indefinido* hasta que se ingresa una cláusula `order by` explícita para ordenar los datos. Para efectos prácticos, considera *indefinido* como sinónimo de *aleatorio*, aunque en realidad no lo sea.

Lo que *indefinido* significa en realidad es que, de un motor a otro, de una versión a otra, incluso de un momento a otro dentro de una misma base de datos, es el propio motor el que define el orden y tu no tienes manera fiable y directa de predecir, definir o manipular dicho orden. En la práctica, los motores va a darte las filas en el mismo orden en consultas sin `order by` consecutivas o cercanas en el tiempo, pues lo que sea que defina el orden en que el motor las procesa, lo va a hacer de manera determinista. No dejes que esa fantasía te engañe. En una misma tabla, motor, versión... unos miles de insert/update/delete después, puedes estar obteniendo los datos en un orden diferente al de las primeras veces.

Si necesitas el orden de inserción, mi recomendación es que agregues un campo auto-incremental a la tabla. Puedes valerte del [pseudo tipo `serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html) para que el campo vaya dejando cada registro *en su lugar*, de manera que después puedas ordenar por dicho campo.

Para no perder el *orden actual* en el que te devuelve un `select` simple sobre la tabla (que repito no necesariamente es el orden de inserción), puedes valerte de una tabla auxiliar y con un campo de tipo `serial` y hacer un:

```
insert into nuevatabla (campos) 
select * from viejatabla
```

Para luego eliminar los datos, crear el cmapo auto-incremental definitivo y ya puedes regresar los datos:

```
insert into viejatabla (campos) 
select campos from nuevatable order by camposerial
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto te ocurre porqué en la partición de la window function, dejas al menos un campo que no es único, la solución es definir el la partición cómo null y asignar el orden que más te convenga para tus datos.

```
select nombre1,
   nombre2,
   target_id,
   etapa,
   orden,
   row_number() over (partition by null order by nombre2,target_id) new_order_id
```

from tabla_principal

| nombre1 | nombre2 | target_id | etapa | orden | new_order_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Juan | González | 50000 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| Juan | González | 60000 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| Juan | González | 70000 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| Juan | González | 80000 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| Juan | Pérez | 10000 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| Juan | Pérez | 10000 | 1 | 1 | 6 |